# OrientDB: how to update a field with data from other vertex

Tags: orientdb

I'm working with some document trying to implement the TF-IDF method to search similarities over documents.
At one point, I need to calculate the Term Frequency (TF). 
I have two vertex in this realation:
 Documento ---> DocWord

DocWord vertex has the following fields:
int frequence
double tf
double idf

Documento has:
int wordCount

I need to update all DocWord tf field with:
frequence/Documento.wordCount

The query I'm trying to run is:

update DocWord set tf = frequence/in("Documento_docwords").wordCount[0];

but this fail.

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
update DocWord set tf = (frequence / in("Documento_docwords").wordCount[0])
```

Comment: Strange, I've tested it on two versions. Which version do you use?

Comment: I have updated the database to 3.0.6 and it work. The error was found in 2.2.29.